# Wrong return format of a Webservice in CakePHP

Tags: php, web-services, cakephp, csv

I have a problem with the return of a Webservice,
the header looks like that :

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->filename.".csv".'"');
```

I collect the data and just return it like that:

```
    foreach($this->output_data as $each_table) {
        foreach($each_table as $each_row) {
            foreach($each_row as $each_key => $each_value){ 
                $string .= Sanitize::escape($each_value).$this->delimiter;
            }                              
            $string .= "\n";
        }            
    }
    print($string);
```

I expect an csv-file as a stream coming back. But the return is a "*Firefox HTML Document*".
I don't understand that.

I have already switched off the view rendering in the controller.
What can i do?

Comment: What cakephp version? In 2.x you dont use header() directly, you use the reponse class instead.

Comment: Also, be sure to disable 'autoRender' ($this->autoRender = false); if you do not use a view-file to output the results. If you're using CakePHP 2.x; more information on the response class (as suggested by @mark) can be found here; [Dealing with content types](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#dealing-with-content-types)

Comment: Its 2.4. You gave me the right hint. I have refactored the code

Comment: $this->response->header(
     array( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. 
       Configure::read('reporting_config')['file_name'].'"'
       ));

   $this->response->type('application/text-csv');
   
   print($this->send_method->get_output_data());

Comment: Maybe cakePHP redirects you to an error page (in View/Errors: error500.ctp or error400.ctp). Have you tried visited the page in a web browser and verified that the output is correctly displayed?

Comment: No it dont. i have solved the problem. i have to use the CakeResponse-Class otherwise it aint work properly.

Comment: @user2140111 if you don't add your solution as an answer, this question is of no value to stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isnt a proper why to just echo some formatted strings out of a Controller or a Model. 
I've find out that theres a Response-Class to use for. Code below:

```
$this->response->header(array( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<filename.ext>"));
$this->response->type('application/text-csv');                     
$this->response->body(<returnData>);
```

be sure to use the right "type".